Two definitions of normal cone of a closed convex cone
I am studying problems of the form
$$\text{minimize } \quad f(x) \quad \text{subject to} \quad G (x) \in  \mathcal{K},\tag{1}$$
where $f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $G:\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ are continuously differentiable functions and $\mathcal{K}$ is a closed convex cone. For me, it is more natural to write the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker (KKT) conditions of this system using normal cones, that is, $$\begin{align*}
f'(x) + G'(x)^{*} \lambda = 0 \quad \text{ and } \quad \lambda \in \mathcal{N}_{\mathcal{K}} (G(x)),
\end{align*}$$ where $\mathcal{N}_{\mathcal{K}}(G(x))$ is the normal cone of the convex set $\mathcal{K}$ at $G(x)$.  However, some authors, like S. M. Robinson, prefer to write the KKT conditions for (1) in the following form $$\begin{align*}
f'(x) + G'(x)^{*} \lambda = 0, \quad \lambda \in \mathcal{K}^{\circ} \quad \text{ and } \quad \left\langle G(x),\lambda \right\rangle = 0,
\end{align*}$$ where $\mathcal{K}^{\circ}$ is the polar cone of $\mathcal{K}$, see this link. So, my question is why $$
 \lambda \in \mathcal{N}_{\mathcal{K}} (G(x)) \iff \lambda \in \mathcal{K}^{\circ} \quad \text{and}\quad \left\langle G(x),\lambda \right\rangle = 0?
$$

It might take a time to notice the equivalence, but it is not complicated to understand. Firstly, I will guarantee that  $$
 v \in \mathcal{N}_{\mathcal{K}} (x) \implies v \in \mathcal{K}^{\circ} \quad \text{and} \quad \left\langle x,v \right\rangle = 0. \tag{1}$$ Indeed, notice that, if $v \in \mathcal{N}_{\mathcal{K}} (x)$, then, by definition of convex normal cone, $$\left\langle z - x, v \right\rangle\leq 0, \quad \text{for all } z \in \mathcal{K}. \tag{*} $$ Consequently, given $z \in \mathcal{K}$, we have that, for any $t>0$, $t z \in \mathcal{K}$ ($\mathcal{K}$ is a cone). Thus, $\left\langle t z - x, v \right\rangle\leq 0$. Thus, $$t \left\langle z, v \right\rangle\leq \left\langle z, x \right\rangle. \tag{**}$$ Hence, it can't be $\left\langle z, v \right\rangle > 0$. Otherwise, we could take $t$ big enough to violate (**). Consequently, $\left\langle z, v \right\rangle \leq 0$ and $v \in \mathcal{K}^{\circ}$.
Additionally, taking $z=0$ in (*), we have $\left\langle x, v \right\rangle \geq 0$. Also, as $x \in \mathcal{K}$, $\left\langle x, v \right\rangle \leq 0$ by the first part. Thus, $\left\langle x, v \right\rangle = 0$ and (1) is proven.
Now, we can prove that
$$ v \in \mathcal{K}^{\circ} \quad \text{and} \quad \left\langle x, v \right\rangle = 0 \implies v \in \mathcal{N}_{\mathcal{K}} (x). \tag{2}.$$ However this is easy, since, for $v$ satisfying $(2)$ and  any $z \in \mathcal{K}$,  $\left\langle z-x, v \right\rangle = \left\langle z, v \right\rangle \leq 0$. Thus $v \in \mathcal{N}_{\mathcal{K}} (x)$ and $(2)$ is valid.
This gives, as corollary, $\mathcal{N}_{\mathcal{K}} (x) \subset \mathcal{K}^{\circ}$, which is a particular case of the answer by noting that $0 \in \mathcal{K}$. However, this equivalence let us conclude even more: $$\mathcal{N}_{\mathcal{K}} (x) = \mathcal{K}^{\circ} \cap \{ x \}^{\perp},$$ when $\mathcal{K}$ is a closed convex cone.
